# How to parse xml file with mixed encoding

Tags: java, xml-parsing

Every night since a few months my service is loading a xml file from foreign webservice. My service parses the xml data and stores them in a database.

```
DocumentBuilder dBuilder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = dBuilder.parse(inputStream);
[...]
```

Tonight the service reported an error:

> MalformedByteSequenceException: Invalid byte 1 of 1-byte UTF-8 sequence

As you can see the xml node `location` contains some broken string inside a `name` tag:

```
<location>
    <name>Park Inn by Radisson Dldorf-Sname>
    <country>Deutschland</country>
    <region></region>
    <city>Düsseldorf</city>
    <zip>40599</zip>
    <street>Am Schönenkamp 9</street>
</location>

[...]

<location>
    <name>BEST WESTERN Hotel City Centre Brl</name>
    <country>Belgien</country>
    <region></region>
    <city>Brüssel</city>
    <zip>1210</zip>
    <street>Square Victoria Regina 9</street>
</location>
```

Other tags like city oder street have well formated utf-8 string.

**I have no control over the xml webservice**. So I have to do it in my service as a hot fix.

My idea was to write an converter, but it wont work:

```
// convert the value of <name>?</name> to an utf8 string
private static String convertToUTF8(String brokenNonUtf8String) throws Exception{
    ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(brokenNonUtf8String.getBytes()); // "UTF-8"
    CharBuffer cb = Charset.forName("windows-1252").decode(bb);
    bb = Charset.forName("UTF-8").encode(cb);
    return new String(bb.array());
}
```

the input is now:

```
<name>Park Inn by Radisson Dï¿½sseldorf-Sï¿½d</name>
```

Any idea how I can fix the issue.

Comment: `brokenString.getBytes()` uses the platform’s default charset to convert the String to bytes.  Is that what you want?

Comment: I tried it also with `UTF-8`, platform default (linux) is UTF-8.

Comment: `new String(bb.array())` also uses the default charset. What is the point of doing `Charset.forName("UTF-8").encode(cb)` followed by `new String(bb.array())`? You're just encoding chars into bytes and back into the exact same chars again.

Comment: Also your method name is misleading. How can a function that takes a Unicode string and returns another Unicode string, be said to "convert to UTF-8"? The name implies it should return a byte array, as only a byte array can contain UTF-8 data.

Comment: One thing worth noting is that "üsse" is correctly encoded in the `<city>` element, but not in the `<name>` element.  This means any working solution probably will have to operate on just the `<name>` element and not the entire XML document.

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou check the code again. it's ok.

Comment: @VGR yes, only the value of name is broken. all other values are ok.

Comment: You've changed your code so that the method takes an argument named "brokenNonUtf8String". In Java, when talking about the String class, there is no such thing as a "UTF8 String" or a "non-UTF8 String". It's a string of 16-bit characters. The concept of UTF-8 only applies to 8-bit bytes. It would help others to help you if you added comments to your method saying what you are trying to do in each line.

Comment: I don’t see a pattern in the data corruption.  Somehow, "üsse" as been replaced with a single U+33CE5 character.  "üsse" as ISO-8559 bytes is fc 73 73 65, whereas the peculiar U+33CE5 character encoded in UTF-8 is f0 b3 b3 a5.  They’re similar, in that the last three bytes are off by exactly 64 (40 hex), but I still don’t see how such a difference could occur.